# Tridion Core Service Reference becomes unknown after I 'Update' the service reference in VS 2010

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I am using tridion core service in my project(VS 2010 .Net Framework 4.0)

When i update the service reference then its become unknown. its removing all references after updating the tridion core service reference.

Can any one suggest me what am i missing?

Comment: If you're on SP1, use the Tridion-provided client DLL instead of generating it. If you're on GA, then I don't know what's happening there, looks like a VS issue.

Comment: Is the CoreService accessible from your development environment?

Comment: @Quirijn: Yes, when i created a project, then i was successfully albe tp add core service reference. But once, i update the service reference then it removed all references.

Comment: Please specify the version of Tridion you are using

Comment: @ChrisSummers: Tridion 2011 SP1

Comment: Use the out-of-the-box dll then dude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, Tridion started shipping a pre-built CoreService client. You can find this dll under [Tridion]\bin\client\Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.

Other than the usual classes, this also includes some optimizations done to the client. Details on how you could use this assembly are available in the [Tridion Practice](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithConfigFile).

Comment: Thanks Nuno, now i am using Core service dll as per your suggestion, but when i use GetListXML function of ICoreService then i am receiving the below error, can you also help me on this. {System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADAA...

Comment: If you're using Windows Authentication, please consider using the `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient` (or `ISessionAwareCoreServiceClient`) instead of ICoreService, with either WsHttp or NetTcp endpoints.

Comment: Currently, I am using CoreServiceClient and its working correctly. I understand, your point also, but i am bit confused, in which case i have to use which class. Now i am stuck in one more place, if you can look into the above question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752003/error-could-not-find-default-endpoint-element-that-references-contract. Thanks