# Error: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I am writing a below code to create a MM component in tridion through core service, but i am getting error to run this service,

```
 public ComponentData GetNewMultimediaComponent(CoreServiceClient Client, string folderUri, string schemaUri, string title, FileInfo fi)
    {
        if (fi.Extension == ".png")
        {
            string mmType = GetMultiMediaType(fi.Extension);
            if (mmType != null)
            {
                string tempLocation = "";

                UploadResponse us = new UploadResponse();
                using (StreamUploadClient streamClient = GetConnection())
                {
                    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent(fi.Name.ToLower(), objfilestream);
                }

                BinaryContentData bcd = new BinaryContentData
                {
                    UploadFromFile = fi.FullName,
                    MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData { IdRef = mmType },
                    Filename = fi.Name,
                    IsExternal = false
                };

                ComponentData res = GetNewComponent(folderUri, schemaUri, title);
                res.ComponentType = ComponentType.Multimedia;
                res.BinaryContent = bcd;

                res = (ComponentData)Client.Create(res, new ReadOptions());
```

In the above code i am getting the error on below line

```
using (StreamUploadClient streamClient = new StreamUploadClient()) 



{System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamUpload' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
       at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait).......
```

Just for update, I am using tridion core services by DLL without config file and create connection successfully.

Connection setting

```
public StreamUploadClient GetConnection()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760,
            ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
            {
                MaxStringContentLength = 10485760,
                MaxArrayLength = 10485760
            },
            Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
            }
        };

        EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://abc/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp");

        StreamUploadClient client = new StreamUploadClient(basicHttpBinding, remoteAddress);
        try
        {
            client.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //log.Error("Error:CoreServiceConectionOpen:Common:" + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

        return client;
    }
```

Now, getting error on below line

```
tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent(fi.Name.ToLower(), objfilestream);

{System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:739a821f-aee2-4eaf-9206-05a1ed19311c+id=1";start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 560 bytes of the response were: '
--uuid:739a821f-aee2-4eaf-9206-05a1ed19311c+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:FilePath xmlns:h="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011">C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp6841.png</h:FilePath></s:Header><s:Body><UploadResponse xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:739a821f-aee2-4eaf-9206-05a1ed19311c+id=1--
'.
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
StreamUploadClient streamClient = new StreamUploadClient()
```

This is a separate endpoint you are trying to connect to. Typically it would pick adress and all other properties of a connection from app.config, but as you don't have any you need to provide all the required parameters yourself, similar to what you do with your CoreService. Refer to app.config sample to see what paremeters you need.

Something like this:

```
    public StreamUploadClient GetConnection()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760,
            ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
            {
                MaxStringContentLength = 10485760,
                MaxArrayLength = 10485760
            },
            MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom,
            Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
            }
        };

        EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://abc/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp");

        StreamUploadClient client = new StreamUploadClient (basicHttpBinding, remoteAddress);
        try
        {
            client.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error:CoreServiceConectionOpen:Common:" + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

        return client;
    }
```

Comment: I am not using the app.config file, now in that case what i need to do? As you can find, i am passing my client object which is having all connection details.

Comment: I understand your point, but when i go like this way the getting below error on above line
tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent(fi.Name.ToLower(), objfilestream);
Error: I understand your point, but when i go like this way the getting below error on above line {System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:739a821f-aee2-4eaf-9206-05a1ed19311c+id=1";start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml...

Comment: Fixed it, `MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom` was missing, see updated sample